# Prevent changes to object returned as a pointer

Tags: c++, constants

I have a function that returns a pointer to an object. Like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    Object* getObject() const { return &obj; };
private:
    Object obj;
}
```

The problem is that I don't the calling function to change the returned object, it might call functions that operate on it internally, but don't change the *obj* inside SomeClass...
An example might be easier to understand:

-If the function returns a pointer to a const Object `const Object* getObject() const` the calling function won't be able to use non-const methods of the object (but I want them to be able).

-If I simply return the pointer, the calling functions might change the object:

```
Object* pointer = sclass.getObject();
*pointer = Object();
```

So the Object inside *sclass* is now a different object (which I don't want to happen).

Is there an workaround?

Comment: The main problem is that I don't want to lose the Object that was previously constructed/initialized...

Comment: Clarification: do you want to be able to use non-const methods on the object but don't want the returned pointer to point to a different object?

Comment: The real question: why returning a pointer and not a reference => it can never be null!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr version:** Return a `const Object *`.

> If the function returns a pointer to a const Object `const Object* getObject() const` the calling function won't be able to use non-const methods of the object (but I want them to be able).

But that's the whole point of `const`-correctness!  Any `Object` method that doesn't modify the observable state of the object should be declared `const`.  If you're consistent about this, then your problem should disappear.  If you're **not** consistent about this, then the whole thing falls apart (which is probably the cause of your problem!).

Obviously, you can't do anything about `const` methods that then subvert things by casting away the `const`-ness of `this`, but that's always a problem.

Comment: If the goal is to allow `const` methods to be used, then one approach might be to copy the object at the call site: `Object foo = *(sclass.getObject()); foo.nonConstMethod();`.  Also, one wonders why the OP isn't using references...

Comment: @cdhowie But then the Object inside SomeClass wouldn't be affected by the called functions... I'm not using references because my program is more complicated than this simple example...

Comment: @TiagoCosta Then you need to decide if this object is immutable or not.  If it's not supposed to change then return a pointer to a constant object, otherwise don't.  You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the user to be able to modify the object, return a pointer to a const object.

Assuming your object is const-correct, that means they'll be able to do anything/everything that doesn't modify the object. If that's not the case, then you want to fix the const-correctness problem so it becomes the case (e.g., all member functions that don't modify the object get marked `const`).

Answer (score 1):

As several others pointed out above, if the Object APIs doesn't enforce const correctness, you can't prevent the client functions from modifying it. So far with the ideal object oriented design.

The only *workaround* (which I wouldn't do myself) could be to return a copy of the object from within the getObject() method.

```
Object* getObject() const { Object* o = new o(obj); return o; };
```

But this comes with unnecessary head-aches like you have to take care of the deletion etc. But, it matches your requirement that the original obj variable is not modified.

Comment: This workaround is more cleanly implemented as `Object getObject() const { return obj; }` -- that's an API change, but so is requiring the user to `delete` the returned pointer.

Comment: @unni, What if there is no constructor that takes obj ? Or what if the object creation is heavy weight  ? It's the const-correctness that is required as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that you could have your cake and eat it too... provided that you have control over the implementation of the `Object` class.

In your particular example, if the assignment operator (`operator=()`) is disabled for `Object`, then the expression

```
*pointer = Object();
```

becomes invalid.

*Note*: of course, the impact of this decision is larger than just `SomeClass::getObject()`: no other part of the code will be able to assign instances of `Object`s to each other.  You will have to decide if this restriction is worth for you

*Note*: to disable `operator=`, declare it as `private` (and no implementation is required):

```
class Object
{
  // ... current member declarations/definitions
  private:
    Object& operator=(const Object&); // no implementation
};
```